# Get a Report within date range in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, reportviewer

I want to get reports within a date range. I have two date time pickers and a view report button. In my sql data base i have a table which include some dates. i want to get reports between dates which in my two date time pickers.when user click the view report button user be able to get a report which include records within those two dates.

Comment: which datbase you are using..?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RDLC for reports. Add parameters in report using report menu.
To pass parameters to rdlc :

```
ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("FromDt",[date]);
ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("ToDt",[date]);

this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]{p1,p2});
```